# Как добавить «нет результатов» если ничего не найдено?

Tags: javascript

Я нашел код для "живого поиска" по списку элементов. Но когда нет результатов, то список просто становиться пустым. Мне надо что-бы появилась надпись "нет результатов".

Вот код:

```html
<div class="game-carts elastic">
  <span id="no-result-id" class="no-result no-result-hide">no result</span>
  <article class="game-item">
    <h3 class="card-hide-title">Title 1</h3>
  </article>
  <article class="game-item">
    <h3 class="card-hide-title">Title 2</h3>
  </article>
  <article class="game-item">
    <h3 class="card-hide-title">Title 3</h3>
  </article>
</div>
```

```js
document.querySelector('#elastic').oninput = function() {
  let val = this.value.trim();
  let elasticItems = document.querySelectorAll('.elastic article h3');
  if (val != '') {
    elasticItems.forEach(function(elem) {
      if (elem.innerText.search((RegExp(val, "gi"))) == -1) {
        elem.closest("article").classList.add('hide');
      } else {
        elem.closest('article').classList.remove('hide');
      }
    });
  } else {
    elasticItems.forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.closest('article').classList.remove('hide');
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let noResult = document.querySelector("#no-result-id");

document.querySelector('#elastic').addEventListener("input", function() {  
  let val = this.value.trim();
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.elastic article h3');
  
  if (!val) { // Ничего не ввели? Показать всё, и прервать;
    noResult.classList.add("hide");
    
    return items.forEach(function _show_all(elem) {
      elem.closest('article').classList.remove('hide');
    });
  }

  /***/

  let anyMatch = false;

  items.forEach(function(elem) {
    let isMatching = new RegExp(val, "gi").test(elem.textContent); // true или false

    anyMatch = anyMatch || isMatching; // (*)
    // isMatching хотя бы один раз окажется true → anyMatch до конца останется true;

    elem.closest("article").classList.toggle('hide', !isMatching);
    // Добавить `hide` если нет совпадения. Иначе - удалить.
  });

  noResult.classList.toggle("hide", anyMatch);
  // Добавить `hide` если есть хотя бы одно совпадение. Иначе - удалить.
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input id="elastic">

<div class="game-carts elastic">
  <span id="no-result-id" class="no-result hide">no result</span>

  <article class="game-item">
    <h3 class="card-hide-title">Aaa</h3>
  </article>
  <article class="game-item">
    <h3 class="card-hide-title">aAb</h3>
  </article>
  <article class="game-item">
    <h3 class="card-hide-title">bbb</h3>
  </article>
</div>
```

**(*)** `anyMatch = anyMatch || isMatching;` — логическое "ИЛИ", работает так:

```
false || false → false
false || true  → true

true  || true  → true
true  || false → true
```

Можно было заменить на

```
if (isMatching) anyMatch = true;
```

Тогда так же: anyMatch стал бы true, из-за хотя бы одного значения true у isMatching

Answer (score 0):

Делаем скрытый элемент `.noResults` со словами "нет результатов".

В начале функции: `let hasAnyResult = false`

После каждого `remove('hide')`: `hasAnyResult = true`

В конце функции: находим `.noResults` и прячем/показываем в зависимости от  `hasAnyResult`